# mod_rewrite 500 internal error caused by regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am getting a 500 internal error when using this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?username=$1 [QSA]
```

After some research I found that the regex at the beginning is causing it, but I couldn't find another solution. Essentially, I am trying to to have 'http://test.com/username' go to 'http://test.com/index.php?username=username'

Comment: Anything else in your file?

Comment: No, but [here](http://www.webforgers.net/mod-rewrite/mod-rewrite-syntax.php) it says that "A RewriteRule ^(.*)$ will shoot a 500 error faster than lightning."

Comment: If there's nothing else in your file, then you've left our the most important first line: `RewriteEngine On`.

Comment: _“After some research I found that the regex at the beginning is causing it”_ – well only in an indirect fashion; the real error here is likely that you created a redirect loop. You need to exclude `index.php` from being rewritten again in the “next round”. A preceding `RewriteCond` using a flag to make sure the requested URI doesn’t match an existing file is usually used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with RewriteRule, but regarding your regex, $1 is the entire subject (http.../username), whereas it seems you want to split the two components at the last solidus, e.g.:

```
^(.*\/)([^\/]*)$
```

That first capture group is greedy so will go to the last solidus.
The second capture group captures while not solidus to end of subject. It may be overkill using NOT-SOLIDUS rather than ".*" but I so favor not using the dot metacharacter unnecessarily that I'd prefer it to the latter.  But you could certainly rewrite that with the dot--in which case if you're going for minimal, you might as well drop the extraneous anchors too:  `(.*\/)(.*)`

Now $1 is `http.../` and $2 is the user name, so you can reformat the line something like this:

```
$1index.php?username=$2 [QSA]
```

PS:  I never used to escape solidus and never had a problem with PCRE for C, but the regex editor/test tool I use (regex101), using "pcre (php)" flags an unescaped solidus as an error, so I have escaped it here.  You may or may not need to, but it should do no harm if you do and it's not needed.  It's not like escaping an alpha unnecessarily where it could be a metacharacter sequence and get you in trouble.